# Acrobat's Javascript console is not working

Tags: javascript, acrobat

Moving from InDesign to Acrobat now, I need to automate a very simple task.  I'll eventually use BridgeTalk to have an InDesign script call Acrobat X and have it do a couple of simple things.  To this end I've been reading up on how to script Acrobat.  Unfortunately, it does not seem anywhere as simple as scripting InDesign or Illustrator.

For one thing, the ExtendScript Toolkit is now useless since Acrobat has a built-in "Javascript Console".  This would be perfectly fine, except that my console seems to be completely broken.  Once I launched it (and it was hellacious just trying to figure *that* out), I type in a simple `3 + 4` in the console and press `Command+Enter`, as noted in [Thom Parker's guide on AcrobatUsers](http://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/javascript_console).  (I don't have a fancy Mac extended keyboard with a numeric keypad, so I have to use `Command+Enter`.)

Nothing happens.

I've tried other things, such as selecting the code first, pressing `Control+Enter` instead, using a different line of code such as `console.println("Hello.");`, etc.  Nothing I do seems to work.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally got my question answered over on [Adobe's forums](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1269551).  I thought I had tried everything, but it turns out that I had not even tried a simple `Shift + Enter`.  Hard to believe, since I thought I'd tried every possible key combination already, but I cannot deny the facts.  Since I only had the small Apple keyboard without the numeric keypad, I suppose this is the only way to get `Enter` instead of `Return` from that key.  At any rate, the answer is now known!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be command-return on MacOS 10.13.6 But thanks for the hint above.